# How to clear the error coming when logging in website in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have completed a website in codeigniter. The login page is working in localhost but when I am uploading the same onto the server, the login page is not working. It is showing a blank white page.

```
$this->load->model("studentsmodel");
$result = $this->studentsmodel->loginCheck($post_data); 
if (!$result) {


$this->notifications->notify('Wrong username or password; Login Failed', 'error');
redirect('site/login', 'refresh');
}
else {
            $this->session->set_userdata('student_id', $result['id']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('stud_cin', $result['stud_cin']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('stud_path', $result['stud_path']);

            redirect('student/id/'.$this->session->userdata('student_id'), 'refresh');

    }
```

This is the code for login page in codeigniter. If there is no value in $result, the notification "wrong username/password" is not working. Also if there is data inside $result , it is not going to else part. In both the cases it is showing a white blank page. Can anyone suggest a solution for this ? I am using CI 2.1. This all is working properly in the localhost but not in the server. Any problm with refresh being used with redirect().

output of $result is

```
Array
(
[id] => 2
[stud_cin] => 11AK11
[stud_path] => photo/no-photo.JPG
)
```

Comment: Make sure the error is not from database. Set `$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;` in `config->database.php`.

Comment: true value is already set for this parameter.

Comment: Data from database in all other pages is working.only the login page is not working on the server. But login page is working in the localhost.

Comment: database connectivity is not the issue..some redirection problm..

Comment: Try this in else condition `redirect('student/id/'.$result['id'])`;

Comment: the if condition is also not working

Comment: No it is not working...Still showing the blank page.

Comment: Are you sure the `$result` is having expected values? Check by `print_($result)` before staring if statement.

Comment: Ya...This code is working in the localhost. But when I am putting the same code in the server, this code is not working. It is not logging in...

Comment: comment the notification line in if statement and also make sure its entering to if condition by giving wrong credentials.

Comment: ys it is working when wrong credentials are given, control is coming inside the if statment but notification is not being displayed.

Comment: And the redirect is working? Now try for else case also.

Comment: no the redirect in the if statment is not working..notification is not getting displayed.  In the case of else part, when correct credentials are given, the control is not coming inside the else part.

Comment: Can you show the value in `$result` in both cases by updating your question.

Comment: updated in the question.

Comment: What response you've got in server for `print_r($result)` ?

Comment: output of $result is Array
(
[id] => 2
[stud_cin] => 11AK11
[stud_path] => photo/no-photo.JPG
)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
$this->load->model("studentsmodel");
$result = $this->studentsmodel->loginCheck($post_data);  

if($result) {
    $id = $this->session->set_userdata('student_id', $result['id']);
    $stud_cin = $this->session->set_userdata('stud_cin', $result['stud_cin']);
    $stud_path = $this->session->set_userdata('stud_path', $result['stud_path']);

    redirect('student/id/'.$id);
}else{
    // $this->notifications->notify('Wrong username or password; Login Failed', 'error');
    redirect('site/login');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->load->model("studentsmodel");
$result = $this->studentsmodel->loginCheck($post_data); 
if($result) {
    if(isset($result['id']) && $result['id'] !== ''){
      $this->session->set_userdata(array(
        'student_id'=>$result['id'],
        'stud_cin'=>$result['stud_cin'],
        'stud_path'=>$result['stud_path']
      ));
      redirect('student/id/'.$result['id'], 'refresh');
    }
    else{
        redirect('site/login', 'refresh');
    }
}
else {
  redirect('site/login', 'refresh');
}
```